# How do I disable the Search Everywhere shortcut?

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA 13 has the new *Search Anywhere* feature. It sounds like it might be useful, but so far it just gets in the way. It's mapped to some kind of magical shift-based shortcut, and it comes up every time I try to shift-click to select text. When this happens, the pop-up flickers and gets into some stuck state, so the only way to get rid of it is to click in the editor pane, which of course loses the selection.

I call the shortcut "magical" because the Search Everywhere action appears in the **Settings** → **Keymap** list with no mapping, so I can't remove this mapping the usual way. Searching the dialog for **search** gives no relevant results.

How can I disable this buggy feature until it's ready for production use, and get back the ability to select text?

Answer (score 60):

To disable the "Search everywhere" feature, you need to invoke "Go to action" (Ctrl+Shift+A), then type "Registry...".

[image]

Scroll down to "ide.suppress.double.click.handler" and check the box.

[image]

Source: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-161094

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+A opens nothing. Single Shift calls the window. "ide.suppress.double.click.handler" is not in the registry list...

Comment: This works for me. Btw, @Zon If Ctrl+Shift+A doesn't work, search the Keymap preferences for "Find Action..."

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+A is the shortcut for "Find Action..." on Windows and Linux. For macOS use Cmd+Shift+A.

Comment: Works fine! Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is great! This feature was driving me insane!

Comment: Great so we need that dialog to disable that same dialog. Also Ctrl-Shift-A is not registered in all the keyboard shortcut themes. Simply showing the menu path would help more.

Comment: Also the key mentioned 'ide.suppress.double.click.handler' is not there anymore. outdated answer?

Comment: This is no longer needed, there's now an option in the UI under `Preferences > Advanced Settings > Disable double modifier key shortcuts`

Answer (score 14):

The settings for the new version have changed

Version: IDEA 2021.2.3

Preference > Advanced Settings

Scroll down to "User Interface", find "Disable double modifier key shortcuts" and check the box.

Answer (score 11):

After updating to build 133.331, I tried assigning a normal shortcut to it in **Settings** → **Keymap**, and that made it stop appearing on double-shift.

Comment: Agreed about it no longer working. Bug report: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=321325

Answer (score 6):

It's called Search Everywhere, and it's present in [keymap](https://www.monosnap.com/image/oPZwbFZGrOdWn34PES4BuSmCL).

For me it's perfectly disabled.

**EDIT** As I'v found it is hardcoded now, and will popup at doubleshift [source](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/lang-impl/src/com/intellij/ide/actions/SearchEverywhereAction.java)

There is also an issue at [jira](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-114694), about this problem.

I hope it will be fixed soon.

Comment: Yes, my keymap list appears the same as yours, with no mapping next to Search Everywhere, but it still pops up. I'm sorry that wasn't clear in my question, which I've now rephrased.

Comment: @DanHulme Sorry. I misunderstand you. I think, you have no such item in keymap. Maybe you can try search in keymap xml file, which is located between other Idea config files. For MacOS ~/Library/Preferences/IdeaIC13/keymaps.

Comment: the issue you have mentioned is marked as fixed, but 8 years later I still have same issue. even though it is specified in keybinding and bind to CTRL-T (for me) still opens with shift shift.

Answer (score 5):

from: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-161094

> In IDEA 2021.2:
>
> You could enable the Settings (Preference on macOS) |
> Advanced Settings | Disable double modifier key shortcuts option to
> disable it.

Comment: Still the same now in 2023! thanks for this.

Answer (score 3):

This problem is still present  under linux (ubuntu amd64 16.10 ) on Android Studio using X11Rdp for remote connection, maybe in other situations too - the Search Everywhere dialog appear on single Shift press.

The answer is here

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-114933#comment=27-603899

Basically you need to 
Open lib/resources.jar/idea/PlatformActions.xml and remove or comment such line:

`<action id="SearchEverywhere" class="com.intellij.ide.actions.SearchEverywhereAction" />`

and repack the jar.

Comment: Modifying a vendor jar may work (and be the ONLY solution for disabling the Double Shift IJ shortcut) but less than elegant for the subscription upgrade path of IJ.

Comment: I couldn't edit the comment, I'm in IJ Ultimate 2017.2.2