# Double Shift functionality in PhpStorm cannot be disabled

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

Double Shift to search everywhere functionality in PhpStorm cannot be disabled.

It's really a dumb shortcut.

Version:

> PhpStorm 2016.3.2
>
> Build #PS-163.10504.2, built on December 20, 2016

Assigning to another shortcut doesn't work anymore:

[How do I disable the Search Everywhere shortcut?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20542053/how-do-i-disable-the-search-everywhere-shortcut)

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205815999-How-to-disable-Double-Shift-for-Search-Everywhere

---

I'm working on MacOS.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 16):

To disable the "Search everywhere" feature, you need to invoke "Go to action" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> on Windows), then type "Registry...".

[image]

Scroll down to "ide.suppress.double.click.handler" and check the box.

[image]

Source: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-161094

Comment: This works on Intellij IDEA CE 2019. And after this I changed the shortcut on keymaps. Now I can use Watch Everywhere without a bad shortcut.

Comment: Thank you! For some reason, my Macbook keyboard keeps double registering shift and opening that search window - it was driving me insane.

Comment: Thanks! How unnecessary complicated and that in 2020.3 still. Super annoying feature, happens way to often that you press it accidentally while there's already an easy shortcut for that anyway.