# Android Studio: "double shift" for "search everywhere" not working

Tags: android-studio, search, keyboard-shortcuts

In Android Studio, there are several related "search" utilities in the same window. The followings work well:

● find class: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>

● find file: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>

● find in path: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

When hovering over the "All" tab (find all/search everyehere), it shows a hint "Double Shift", indicating the shortcut key.

However, when pressing Shift twice, nothing happened.

There isn't an `ide.suppress.double.click.handler` to be unchecked as in IntelliJ IDEA, as in the following post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48894157/15901500

What is the keyboard shortcut for "search everywhere" in Android Studio?

Comment: I just updated Android Studio to Arctic Fox Version and i faced same issue, before update `Double Shift` is used to search `Find Class` instead of `All`, now same can be done by **Ctrl** + **N**, i haven't updated shortcuts but still it's changed, i'm way much comfortable with old one and now it's ruined

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the exact answer to your question but there is something you should know:
When I **double press SHIFT** this box appears that is not what you would expect for search everywhere and it doesn't give search results everywhere not specially in the project:
[image]

As you can see below it even doesn't return the phrase used in project and in the line just above the box:
[image]

But in the other hand **CRTL+SHIFT+F** returns what I expected to be returned:
[image]

In conclusion I feel that by having **Double Shift** not working you are not loosing anything useful and functional.
Even though I couldn't answer your question I thought it might worth sharing...

**PS:** As you can see below you can press the magnifier icon to show the useless search Everywhere window:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the information. Yeah, the "Search Everywhere" turns out to be not quite useful.